# Flutter Container background color and gradient

Tags: flutter, gradient

I can't figure out how to make such container with gradient. Is it possible to make such a background with flutter?

[image]

Comment: This has the info you need i believe ->
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gradient-in-flutter-applications/

Comment: Seems It is having 3 radial gradient on different offset.

Comment: yes, It is clear that there have three gradients, but I dont have idea how to do this

Comment: Maybe you can create 3 different container with low opacity ratios, and stack them.

Comment: you can use this [DecorationStack](https://gist.github.com/pskink/91b658f23c8d2f6fa6c73ae5c29173b2#file-decoration_misc-dart-L53) and pass multiple `BoxDecoration`s as `decorations: [ ...`